# Samba started twice on boot up after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: samba, services, init.d

the second attempt results in a failure:

```
Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server[74G[[31mfail[39;49m]
```

I'd like to figure out where the second attempt is coming from and remove it.

bootl.log:

```
 * Stopping Read required files in advance[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Mount filesystems on boot[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Populate and link to /run filesystem[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Populate and link to /run filesystem[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Track if upstart is running in a container[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Initialize or finalize resolvconf[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that virtual filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that virtual filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge udev events into upstart[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that remote filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting device node and kernel event manager[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting load modules from /etc/modules[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting cold plug devices[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting log initial device creation[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping load modules from /etc/modules[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Uncomplicated firewall[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that the rootfs is mounted[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge socket events into upstart[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Clean /tmp directory[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting userspace bootsplash[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Send an event to indicate plymouth is up[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping userspace bootsplash[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Clean /tmp directory[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting SMB/CIFS File Server[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that local filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount filesystems on boot[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Flush boot log to disk[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting flush early job output to logs[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Enabling additional executable binary formats[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Flush boot log to disk[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping cold plug devices[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting D-Bus system message bus[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping flush early job output to logs[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping log initial device creation[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting modem connection manager[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save udev log and update rules[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting bluetooth daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save udev log and update rules[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure virtual network devices[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge file events into upstart[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting system logging daemon[74G[ OK ]
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting SystemD login management service[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting AppArmor profiles       [100G 
[94G[ OK ]
 * Setting up X socket directories...       [100G 
[94G[ OK ]
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting anac(h)ronistic cron[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting deferred execution scheduler[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting network connection manager[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping crash report submission daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Restore Sound Card State[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping anac(h)ronistic cron[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting ACPI daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server[74G[[31mfail[39;49m]
```

sudo initctl list

```
mountnfs-bootclean.sh start/running
nmbd start/running, process 1243
rsyslog start/running, process 685
tty4 start/running, process 788
udev start/running, process 268
upstart-udev-bridge start/running, process 262
vmware-tools start/running
mountall-net stop/waiting
passwd stop/waiting
rc stop/waiting
startpar-bridge stop/waiting
ureadahead-other stop/waiting
whoopsie stop/waiting
apport start/running
smbd start/running, process 517
systemd-logind start/running, process 750
tty5 start/running, process 793
console-setup stop/waiting
gpu-manager stop/waiting
hwclock-save stop/waiting
irqbalance stop/waiting
plymouth-log stop/waiting
mountall.sh start/running
failsafe stop/waiting
rfkill-store stop/waiting
atd start/running, process 845
dbus start/running, process 559
resolvconf start/running
failsafe-x stop/waiting
mounted-var stop/waiting
plymouth-shutdown stop/waiting
plymouth stop/waiting
udev-fallback-graphics stop/waiting
usb-modeswitch-upstart stop/waiting
checkroot.sh start/running
network-manager start/running, process 869
control-alt-delete stop/waiting
hwclock stop/waiting
mounted-proc stop/waiting
alsa-store stop/waiting
setvtrgb stop/waiting
shutdown stop/waiting
vmware-tools-thinprint stop/waiting
cron start/running, process 846
lightdm start/running, process 923
mountkernfs.sh start/running
alsa-restore stop/waiting
mountall stop/waiting
mounted-debugfs stop/waiting
binfmt-support start/running
console stop/waiting
mounted-run stop/waiting
acpid start/running, process 984
bluetooth start/running, process 586
checkfs.sh start/running
checkroot-bootclean.sh start/running
mountnfs.sh start/running
ufw start/running
kmod stop/waiting
plymouth-stop stop/waiting
rcS stop/waiting
reload-smbd stop/waiting
wait-for-state stop/waiting
bootmisc.sh start/running
flush-early-job-log stop/waiting
friendly-recovery stop/waiting
rc-sysinit stop/waiting
samba-ad-dc stop/waiting
upstart-socket-bridge start/running, process 395
pulseaudio stop/waiting
mountdevsubfs.sh start/running
tty2 start/running, process 799
upstart-file-bridge start/running, process 679
anacron stop/waiting
udevtrigger stop/waiting
mtab.sh start/running
tty3 start/running, process 800
container-detect stop/waiting
mounted-dev stop/waiting
udev-finish stop/waiting
alsa-state stop/waiting
hostname stop/waiting
mountall-reboot stop/waiting
network-interface (lo) start/running
network-interface (eth0) start/running
tty1 start/running, process 1702
mountall-shell stop/waiting
mounted-tmp stop/waiting
plymouth-ready stop/waiting
plymouth-splash stop/waiting
plymouth-upstart-bridge stop/waiting
udevmonitor stop/waiting
mountall-bootclean.sh start/running
network-interface-security (network-manager) start/running
network-interface-security (network-interface/eth0) start/running
network-interface-security (network-interface/lo) start/running
network-interface-security (networking) start/running
networking start/running
tty6 start/running, process 803
dmesg stop/waiting
procps stop/waiting
rfkill-restore stop/waiting
console-font stop/waiting
network-interface-container stop/waiting
ureadahead stop/waiting
```

Comment: Sorry what? `smbd` and `nmbd` are separated services and can start independently one of the other. Also, what you mean with "the second attempt results in a failure"? what are you tying to do?

Comment: there are two entries in boot.log for samba, the second is a failure

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=40Rp3L9q

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `initctl list`

Comment: so where should I look for these samba startup attempts?

Comment: You sure you did it with `sudo`? `sudo initctl list`?

Comment: edited with sudo initctl list output

Comment: Since you asked for `sudo initctl list` perhaps you can comment on it?

Comment: Same here. It seems to be a bug...

Answer (score 10):

Per default samba active directory and domain controller service will be started in addition to smbd and nmbd. For a standalone server this is not neccesary. Just set the service to manual startup to get rid of the [fail] message with the following statement as root:

```
echo manual | tee /etc/init/samba-ad-dc.override
```

Comment: Note that it's the command to the right of the `|` pipe that needs to be run as root. (`echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/samba-ad-dc.override` will succeed at causing `/etc/init/samba-ad-dc.override` to exist and have `manual` as its sole contents, overwriting the file if it already exists. In a root shell, `echo manual > /etc/init/samba-ad-dc.override` would be sufficient. Except in a root shell, `sudo echo manual | tee /etc/init/samba-ad-dc.override`--which many people would think to type--would not work.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems above method is for `upstart` which has been deprecated since 15.04. If `systemd` is in use, use this method instead:

```
sudo systemctl disable samba-ad-dc
```