# samba-ad-dc.override to fix SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server failing to start

Tags: 14.04, samba, cifs, smb

According to this post ([Samba started twice on boot up after upgrade to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455418/samba-started-twice-on-boot-up-after-upgrade-to-14-04)), you can run "echo manual | tee /etc/init/samba-ad-dc.override" in order to create a file and fix the issue with one of the two listed "SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server" failing to start on initial boot.

I followed these instructions, and it did indeed get rid of the "SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server" listing that was showing up as [fail] - in fact I think it got rid of both "SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server" listings.

However, according to the last comment on that above link, the samba-ad-dc.override could actually have other contents in it - was just wondering what else might be put in that file and what it might accomplish?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, that file doesn't exist; which means it has no contents unless you already created it.

Comment: Actually it **does** exist on my upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.